# torch.cuda.is_available() is False only in Jupyter Lab/Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I tried to install CUDA on my computer. After doing so I checked in my Anaconda Prompt and is appeared to work out fine.

[image]

However, when I started Jupyter Lab from the same environment, `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns False. I managed to find and follow [this solution](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-cuda-is-available-returns-false-only-for-jupyter-notebook/78281), but the problem still persisted for me.

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with similar causes:

[Not able to import Tensorflow in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939415/not-able-to-import-tensorflow-in-jupyter-notebook/62939942#62939942)

You are probably using other environment than the one you are using outside jupyter.

Try open Anaconda Navigator, navigate to Environments and active your env, navigate to Home and install jupyter notebook, then lunch jupyter notebook from the navigator. This should solve the issue.

In linux, you can check using `!which python` inside jupyter.

In windows you can use:

```
import sys, os
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

To find where is the python that you are using.
See if the path matches.